# i m not getting correct output?

Tags: java, string

```java
import java.util.Scanner;

public class test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int n = sc.nextInt();
        String[] in = new String[n];
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            in[i] = sc.nextLine();
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            System.out.println(in[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Input:

```
2
Ankit
```

Output:

```
Ankit
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Scanner is skipping nextLine() after using next() or nextFoo()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13102045/scanner-is-skipping-nextline-after-using-next-or-nextfoo)

Answer (score 1):

That's because of the **Scanner.nextInt** method does not read the newline character in your input created by hitting **"Enter"** and so the call to **Scanner.nextLine** returns after reading that newline.
There are two options to resolve this issue,

**1. read the input through Scanner.nextLine and convert your input to the proper format you need**

```
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    int n = Integer.parseInt(sc.nextLine());
    
    String[] in = new String[n];
    
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        in[i] = sc.nextLine();
    }
    
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        System.out.println(in[i]);
    }
```

**2. Add Scanner.nextLine call after each Scanner.nextInt**

```
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    int n = sc.nextInt();
    sc.nextLine();
    
    String[] in = new String[n];
    
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        in[i] = sc.nextLine();
    }
    
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        System.out.println(in[i]);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

the Scanner class skips next line after nextint so you can fix it by editting your code like this-

```
import java.util.Scanner; 
public class test {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
    int n=sc.nextInt();
    sc.nextLine();  
    String[] in=new String[n];
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        in[i]=sc.nextLine();
    }
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        System.out.println(in[i]);
    }
    
    }
}
```